# Getting all visible Nodes from Infragistics UltraTree

Tags: c#, winforms, infragistics, ultratree

I have 1 root node and many child nodes of that root node.

I want to get all of the visible nodes key.

The recursive code block like below;

```
public void PrintNodesRecursive(UltraTreeNode oParentNode)
{  
    foreach (UltraTreeNode oSubNode in ultraTree1.Nodes[0].Nodes)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(oSubNode.Key.ToString());
        PrintNodesRecursive(oSubNode);
    }             
}

private void ultraButton3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    PrintNodesRecursive(ultraTree1.Nodes[0]);
}
```

However messagebox always show me '1' value. It doesn't count and endless loop happens.

How can I make it happen?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try like this;

```
    public void PrintNodesRecursive(UltraTreeNode oParentNode)
    {
        if (oParentNode.Nodes.Length == 0)
        {
            return;
        }
        foreach (UltraTreeNode oSubNode in oParentNode.Nodes)
        {
            if(oSubNode.Visible)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(oSubNode.Key.ToString());
            }
            PrintNodesRecursive(oSubNode);
        }
    }
```

Also, put the `visible` condition in the loop.

Comment: The extra length check is unnecessary. `foreach` on an empty collection is a no-op anyways.

Comment: You are right, I put that logic because of provide better understanding.

Comment: Thank you, this works too. however it shows me all nodes/subnodes not only visible ones. What can we do about it ?

Comment: I put the "oSubNode.Visible" logic in the loop.

Comment: @Rainman yes, i tried with that. however, still getting all nodes.

Comment: So, All of the nodes might be visible ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/161362/discussion-between-john-true-and-rainman).

Answer (score 1):

You made a simple programming error. This line:

```
foreach (UltraTreeNode oSubNode in ultraTree1.Nodes[0].Nodes)
```

should probably be

```
foreach (UltraTreeNode oSubNode in oParentNode.Nodes)
```

Otherwise, every recursion step starts again from the top.